# Real zeros of the zeta function

Tags: roots, riemann-zeta

How does one show that the negative even integers make up all the real zeros of the zeta function? That is, how does one show that there are no real zeros on the interval [0,1]?

I am aware that you can in fact compute the zeros numerically, but I am interested in a more noncomputational argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compairing series and integral, we get
$$\zeta(s) = \int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{t^s} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{n^s} -\int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{dt}{t^s} \right) = \frac{1}{s-1} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{n^s} -\int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{dt}{t^s} \right).$$
The RHS is holomorphic for $Re(s) >0$, so equality holds for all $s \in (0,\infty)$.

Let $s \in (0,\infty)$. Since $f(t):=1/t^s$ is decreasing, we have
$$0 \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( f(n) -\int_{n}^{n+1} f(t)dt \right) < f(1) = 1.$$
Hence $\zeta(s) < \frac{1}{s-1} + 1$, which implies that $\zeta(s)<0$ for $s \in (0,1)$.

Comment: I am confused about this step: $0 \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( f(n) -\int_{n}^{n+1} f(t)dt \right) < f(1)$. Could you give an interpretation?

Comment: @Improve It is because $f(n+1) \leq \int_n^{n+1} f(t)dt \leq f(n)$.

Comment: Yes, both inequalities are clear now. The first because you sum strictly positive terms, and the second because you get a telescoping series when applying the inequality you just posted. Just to make sure, the argument would not make sense if s was not real? Edit: Also, the second sentence about the RHS beeing holomorphic, I am a bit weak on complex analysis, so could you ellaborate?

Comment: The serie $\sum_{n}( n^{-s} -\int_n^{n+1} t^{-s} dt)$ satisfies $n^{-s} -\int_n^{n+1} t^{-s} dt = O(n^{-s-1})$ (just compute the integral).
Hence the serie congerve uniformally on every compact subset of $\{ Re > 0\}$. So the limit is holomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Analytic continuation of the zeta function to $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 0$ gives (see (16)-(20) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html))

$$\zeta(s)=\frac1{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$$

The sum is the Dirichlet $\eta$ function, which can be seen is positive for all real $s > 0$:

$$\eta(s)=\underbrace{\frac1{1^s}-\frac1{2^s}}_{>0}+\underbrace{\frac1{3^s}-\frac1{4^s}}_{>0}+\dots+...\underbrace{\frac1{(2k-1)^s}-\frac1{(2k)^s}}_{>0}+\dots$$

Since $1-2^{1-s}$ is negative for all $s\in(0,1)$, we can conclude that $\zeta(s) < 0$, i.e. $\zeta$ has no zeroes in the range $(0,1)$.

Comment: Good argument. ${}$